# How to select list class properties on the base max value in each group?

Tags: c#, linq

How to select list class properties on the base max value in each group?
I tried like below but not get success..

```
public class STUDENT_DETAIL
{            
    public long? Registration_Id { get; set; }
    public string Admission_No { get; set; }
    public long? Class_Id { get; set; }
    public long? Section_Id { get; set; }
    public long? Academic_Year_Id { get; set; }
    public string Student_First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Student_Last_Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date_Of_Birth { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Blood_Group { get; set; }            
}

List<CUSTOM_STU_DETAIL> academicYr = new List<CUSTOM_STU_DETAIL>();

public PartialViewResult ReAdmission_of_Student(long? CompanyId, long? CompanyLocationId, long AcademicId, long? ClassID, long? SectionID)
{
    if (CompanyId != null && CompanyId != 0 && CompanyLocationId != null && CompanyLocationId != 0 && ClassID != null && ClassID != 0 && SectionID != null && SectionID != 0)
    {
        academicYr = (from s in db.Student_Re_Admission
                             order by s.Re_Admission_Id descending
                             group s by s.Registration_Id into stugrp           

                                   //let topp = stugrp.Max(x => x.Re_Admission_Id)

        select new CUSTOM_STU_DETAIL
        {
        }).ToList();
    }

    ViewBag.Student_List = StuList.ToList();

    return PartialView();
}
```

Actually I want like below sql query concept in linq..

```
select * from [Student_Re_Admission] where [Re_Admission_Id] in( SELECT max(Re_Admission_Id) FROM [Student_Re_Admission] group by Registration_Id )
```

Comment: FYI - it's bad practice to name classes in caps. Use camelCase :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Re_Admission_Id` in `STUDENT_DETAIL`, so use `Admission_No` instead of.

```
var maxReAdmissionIds =
            (from s in db.Student_Re_Admission
             group s by s.Registration_Id
                 into grp
                 select (grp.Max(p => Convert.ToInt32(p.Admission_No))).ToString())
                 .ToList();
```

Group by `Registration_Id` than select the `Admission_No` to a list at first.

```
var result = from s in db.Student_Re_Admission
             where maxReAdmissionIds.Contains(s.Admission_No)
             select s;
```

Then, use the list to get the result.
But another concern is if `maxReAdmissionIds` more than 2100 elements will cause "sql where in too much element" exception.

Comment: where is the my class list selection?

Comment: I not want var I want my class as data type for lists

Comment: @abbasahmed [about "var"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/bb383973.aspx), in this case, `result` will be `IEnumerable<Student_Re_Admission>`, you can cast it to `List<Student_Re_Admission>` by .ToList().